# Brightness and volume controls delayed when using internal speakers

Tags: keyboard, display, audio, catalina

*This is clearly related to [Delay when using the volume buttons](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116572/delay-when-using-the-volume-buttons), but that was about a wireless keyboard and many generations of macOS ago.*

### Problem:

When Internal Speakers are selected in the control panel, adjusting volume OR brightness via the corresponding keyboard keys can be *hugely* delayed: I just measured a 58 second delay for both. And when adjusting the audio, there's no audio feedback.

But when I select "Display Audio" (I have a Thunderbolt / Cinema display), adjusting both volume and brightness respond promptly (and for volume, I hear the audio feedback.)

*(I find it especially interesting that adjusting the brightness is affected by the selection of audio output.)*

Any thoughts on a cause and a possible fix?

### More details:

- OS: macOS 10.15.1 (19B88), aka macOS Catalina
- HW: MacBookPro11,2
- Display(s):

  - Built-In Retina LCD (2880 x 1800 Retina)
  - Thunderbolt Display (2560 x 1440 (QHD/WQHD - Wide Quad High Definition)

Comment: Please mention if you've tried suggestions from that question and its multiple answers.

Comment: @ankii: A careful reading of the original question suggests that most of the solutions given aren't applicable here.  At this moment, though, it's working normally so I can't test other solutions.  (It's the Heisenberg Principle at work: the closer you look for a bug, the less likely it is to be there.)